# "Allow this application to run when you are not present" in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Why is my add-on asking for this permission? Tried looking through the docs and couldn't find anything.

[image: the permission request I'm getting]

As far as I know, my application doesn't run when the user isn't present! (It requires the user to select a range in Google Sheets, press a button in custom UI, and call an external API). Are there any tips for what I should look for to find the offending code or configuration that's triggering such a permission request?

Comment: Do you have any triggers installed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this answer?

### 1. Quick confirming

> Allow this application to run when you are not present

When above authorization message is displayed, it means that the methods which use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp` is used in the project. You can see the scope in the project at File -> Project properties -> Scopes. The methods which need such scope are in especially `ScriptApp`. When `getProjectTriggers()`, `getUserTriggers()`, `deleteTrigger()`, `newTrigger()` are used in the project, such scope is automatically detected.
If you have already noticed that such methods are used in your project, this section might be an answer.

### 2. Investigating

If you have already noticed that such methods are **NOT** used in your project, please check this section.

When the GAS project is saved, the scopes which are used in the project are detected by the automatic detection. This automatic detection also works for commented out methods. Furthermore, even when each word is separated, the word is detected, because the automatic detection works for the special words, as follows.

```
ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()

// .... do something

// newTrigger  <--- this is put as a comment
```

When above script is in the project, the automatic detection says that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp` is required. But in this sample, `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` doesn't require `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp`.

If you want to confirm whether the authorization which uses such scope is required to run your script, you can do it using "Manifests". Recently, "Manifests" was added to GAS project. Using "Manifests", the automatic detection of scopes can be stopped. By this, you can know whether the detected scopes are actually required to the project. In order to confirm this, please do the following flow.

1. On the script editor.
2. File -> Project properties -> Scopes
3. Copy current scopes.
4. View -> Show Manifest file

   - `appsscript.json` appears.
5. Please add the copied scopes to `appsscript.json` as follows.

The default `appsscript.json` is

```
{
  "timeZone": "### your timezone ###",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

For this, please add the copied scopes as follows. And please save this.

```
{
  "timeZone": "### your timezone ###",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "scope2",
    "scope3",
    ...
  ]
}
```

After added `oauthScopes`, at first, please confirm whether your script works fine. And then, remove `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp` from `oauthScopes`, and run again. At this time, if there is an error, it is indicated that the errored line uses the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp`.

### Note :

- Also there is a possibility that the authorization `Allow this application to run when you are not present` is not related to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp`.

  - When you see the scopes in your project, if `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp` is not included, after added the scopes to `appsscript.json`, please confirm the error line by removing scopes one by one.

### References :

- [ScriptApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app)
- [Manifests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests)

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with my add-on, and realised the `script.scriptapp` scope was being automatically detected because I had implemented the `onOpen` and `onInstall` methods (to install the add-on menu items).

If you want to see the scopes detected for your google app scripts, in the Script Editor, select Project Properties and then the Scopes tab.

[image]

This code is directly from the [Google Add-on's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs) - and it's a pity it causes such a scary looking permission request.

```
/**
 * Creates a menu entry in the Google Docs UI when the document is opened.
 * This method is only used by the regular add-on, and is never called by
 * the mobile add-on version.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trggr. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trggr is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}


/**
 * Runs when the add-on is installed.
 * This method is only used by the regular add-on, and is never called by
 * the mobile add-on version.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onInstall trggr. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trggr is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode. (In practice, onInstall trggrs always
 *     run in AuthMode.FULL, but onOpen may be AuthMode.LIMITED or
 *     AuthMode.NONE.)
 */
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
```

Comment: You have to wonder how many Add-ons have this permission and the developers have no clue (I was one of them until I found this question and answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in one of Addons. The problem was that the default Google template has some comments that will trigger this scope to be detected.

```
@param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger. To
    determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
    running in, inspect e.authMode.



@param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onInstall trigger. To
    determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
    running in, inspect e.authMode. (In practice, onInstall triggers always
    run in AuthMode.FULL, but onOpen triggers may be AuthMode.LIMITED or
    AuthMode.NONE.)
```

If you are sure that you are not using this scope anywhere else in your project (using programmatic triggers, using ScriptApp etc), then remove these comments and the scope will be removed.

Comment: Haha. "that will **trigger** this scope to be detected." Pun intended?