# Finding script.container.ui API In Google Cloud library

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-docs

I am trying to get OAuth setup for a marketplace app I have been working on for Google Docs. I need to apply the scopes that my project uses to the OAuth API . I have checked the project and it uses 2 scopes

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
```

I was able to apply the google docs API and found the scope for `/auth/documents`. I have enabled the scripts API but `script.container.ui` is not part of this library. I have searched through the store and I cant find it. I also can't find any other reports of people not being able to find it. Anyone know how I can enable this scope?

Comment: Are you saying that you can't find which API you're using that needs that scope? The thing that causes a lot of confusion is that Google's "AI" adds scopes by scanning source. Certain words will cause the scope to be added, **even if they're in comments.** See how the word "trigger" will cause this to happen. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51762703/1168342

Answer (score 6):

Add it manually, it is the window where you add the scopes at the end it says to add scopes manually, press there and paste the scopes that do not appear in the previous list.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First, in the API Console, enable the Apps Script API. Second, as outlined in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55820369/6255000), click the *manually paste* link that will open a paste box to paste in the URL https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui. It does not appear on searching.