# Google Script Add-on requires access for an unused scope

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth, scopes

I've built an add-on for google spreadsheets using google apps script and I can't figure out why it asks for Drive permissions.
The `Drive API` is not enabled, I'm not using `DriveApp` class anywhere in the project and the `driveapp` scope is also not defined anywhere, but it shows up in the OAuth Authorization Screen and makes the app to be unverified:
[image]
[image]

These are the scopes from the Project Properties:
[image]

Scopes defined in the `appscript.json` file:

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
```

And finally, scopes authorized in the Google Cloud Platform, OAuth consent screen:
[image]

Comment: Google SpreadSheets is part of Drive. This link shows the required OAuth scopes: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

Comment: Did you had a look at [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179449/allow-this-application-to-run-when-you-are-not-present-in-google-apps-script/48200656)? You might use the DriveApp in a comment. If that's not the case, try to remove scopes one by one and you'll see which one ask for Drive permissions. I would start with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage` which might store scripts in the user's Google Drive, thus asking for Drive permissions

Comment: @jwilleke does it means that the `driveapp` scope is not required to be verified in the OAuth consent screen?

Comment: Can you provide your code to see where the call to Drive might come from?

Comment: @ziganotschka I'm not using Drive anywhere and the Drive API is not enabled

Comment: If there's a api call that requires drive permissions, it might be added. Could you list all the apis enabled for this project? I'll start by blaming the analytics api.... Disable the api and see?

Comment: It uses only Google Analytics API. I think it's the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` scope that requires access to Drive

Comment: I would try removing `" . . . ://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit" and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you do not want to share your code, I recommend you to troubleshoot by reducing it to very basic and gradually adding more code, to see which line triggers the request for drive scopes.

Comment: @ziganotschka the code is huge and it would be a pain to reduce it. I will try to remove the scopes one by one and see it I can figure out the problem this way.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I had the `driveapp` scope added in the G Suite Marketplace configuration and the OAuth screen don't ask anymore for the Drive permissions after removing that scope. The "Unverified" app message also don't show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) of Google Sheets, you need few Drives authorizations to use the API **if you do not work with public data**.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive (Request this scope only when it is strictly necessary.)

Comment: Then the Drive permission is not the one making the app to be unverified, there must be something else